# Pandas DataFrame: most data in columns are 'float' , I want to delete the row which is 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
wu=pd.DataFrame({'a':['hhh',2,3,4,5],'b':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5]}
```

I want to delete the row with 'hhh', because all datas in 'a' are numbers.
The original data size is huge. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Convert `a` using `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.a = pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce')
df

     a    b
0  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  NaN
4  5.0  5.0
```

Non-Numeric columns are coerced to `NaN`. You can then drop this row -

```
df.dropna(subset=['a'])

     a    b
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  NaN
4  5.0  5.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Another alternative is using `str.isdigit` -

```
df.a.str.isdigit()

0    False
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Filter as such -

```
df[df.a.str.isdigit().isnull()]

   a    b
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
3  4  NaN
4  5  5.0
```

Notes -

- This won't work for float columns
- If the numbers are also as strings, then drop the `isnull` bit -

  ```
  df[df.a.str.isdigit()]
  ```

Comment: Nice! I think there could be some sort of warning for creating float values. Something in the lines of: pd.to_numeric returns floats if there are nan-values.

Comment: @AntonvBR Interestingly, it coerces the column to floats only if NaNs are generated as a result of coercing the non-numeric values. Otherwise, it attempts to preserve the current dtype :)

Comment: Exactly, because of the fact that integers can't represent NaN values.

Comment: A thought just crossed my mind. In this specific case we could even use this mask: `pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce').notnull()` which would work for floats too. Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

wu=pd.DataFrame({'a':['hhh',2,3,4,5],'b':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5]})

#wu = wu[wu.a.str.contains('\d+',na=False)]

#wu = wu[wu.a.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]

wu = wu[wu.a.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, np.int64)))]

print(wu)
```

Note that you missed out a closing parenthesis when creating your DataFrame.

I tried 3 ways, but only the third one worked. You can always try the other ones (commented out) if that works for you. Do let me know if it works on the larger dataset.

Comment: Please don't use apply when you don't need to.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with using it. Can you explain why apply is a bad choice?

Comment: Of course. `apply` is a convenience function that hides a loop. If there are N ways to solve the problem, `apply` is quite consistently the slowest of them. It provides no vectorisation, and does not assume anything about your function. Furthermore, it has a lot of overhead (just look at the source code), so quite often a simple python loop doing the same thing is _faster_.

Comment: Had the same discussion with another user here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027171/create-a-variable-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-information-in-the-dataframe/48027391#48027391

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How can this be solved with vectorisation ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hhh',2,3,4,5],'b':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5]})

df.drop(df[df['a'].apply(type) != int].index, inplace=True)
```

if you just want to view the appropriate rows:

```
df.loc[df['a'].apply(type) != int, :]
```